# How Can I Add my Nested List to Pandas DataFrame as a row ? (Best way)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an nested list like that;

`[[1,2,3,...,48], [96,97,98,...,144], [145,...,192]]` --> means always list of length in inside is 48

and I have empty pandas dataframe like that (**I wrote nan values ​​to show better.**);

```
   one two three ... forty-eight
0  NaN NaN  NaN  ...     NaN
```

I want add nested list element (which is every single list) to dataframe as a row.

```
   one two three  ... forty-eight
0  1    2   3     ...     48
1  49   50  51    ...     99
```

**How do I do this in the best way?**

Comment: What are your thoughts on this, and what have you already tried?

Comment: I tried convert list element to pandas Dataframe and add row by row with pd.concat. But it didn't help.

Comment: do you really have to copy it into empty dataframe? Maybe use `list` to create directly `DataFrame` - `pd.DataFrame(your_list, columns=['one', 'two', 'three', ...])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create directly `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [ 
    [1,2,3], 
    [4,5,6], 
    [7,8,9] 
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   one  two  three
0    1    2      3
1    4    5      6
2    7    8      9
```